# Let $x=\frac{1}{3}$ or $x=-15$ satisfies the equation,$\log_8(kx^2+wx+f)=2.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Let $x=\frac{1}{3}$ or $x=-15$ satisfies the equation,$\log_8(kx^2+wx+f)=2.$If $k,w,f$ are relatively prime positive integers,then find the value of $k+w+f.$

---

The given equation is $\log_8(kx^2+wx+f)=2$ i.e. $kx^2+wx+f=64$
Since $x=\frac{1}{3}$ or $x=-15$ satisfies the equation,so
$\frac{k}{9}+\frac{w}{3}+f=64.............(1)$
$225k-15w+f=64............................(2)$
I need to find $k,w,f$ from these equations,but i need three equations to find three variables.I am stuck here.

Comment: Is it correct that $x = \frac{1}{3}$ OR $x = -15$? So they don't need to satisfy both at the same time. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminating $f$ gives $44k=3w$. Take $w=44,k=3$. Then we get $f=49$. Note that the general solution is $k=3h,w=44h,f=64-15h$, but the requirement that the numbers are relatively prime positive integers forces $h=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint $gcd(k,w,f)=1$ as they are relatively prime. Or thats a quadratic so product of roots is $-5=\frac{f-64}{k}$ and sum of roots is $\frac{44}{3}=-\frac{w}{f}$ can you get all in w and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

At $x_0=\frac{1/3+(-15)}{2}$ there will be an extermum, since the value of the function at these two points are the same. Hence the derivative of the quadratic function, which is $2kx+w$ should be zero at $x_0$. That gives you the third equation.